# Stack frame boundary

Tags: memory, stack-variables

I've disassembled some C/C++ codes and realized the stack boundary is specified at beginning of a procedure, somehow like this :

```
1. push ebp
2. mov ebp , esp
3. sub esp , <power> ; <power> is specified by mpreferred-stack-boundary=2^power
```

The above code is used to create stack frames, But What I need to know is why this subtract is used, Cause the stack grows down (by using push for local variables) and such the subtract causes :

```
---------------------------- ^
by sub esp,<power> <---- esp |
.                            |
.                            |
.                            |
---------------------------- |
esp <---- esp                |
---------------------------- |
ret address                  |
---------------------------- |
```

The above picture shows that.So when in the rest of code if you have such the following codes:

```
push var1
```

It should be taken at the top of it so it looks like this :

```
-----------------------------
var1 (4 byte)                
-----------------------------^
by sub esp,<power> <---- esp |
.                            |
.                            |
.                            |
---------------------------- |
esp <---- esp                |
---------------------------- |
ret address                  |
---------------------------- |
```

So the space between esp and var1 is going to be free without any use ?
that's what I want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the space between esp and var1 is going to be free without any use
>   ? that's what I want to know.

That stack space is used for the function's local variables (also known as "stack variables").

Here's a nice animated GIF that shows a function's stack frame being created and used to store local variables:

[image: GIF]

Comment: So thanks.I've completely forgotten that variables are put in stacks by something like this(for instance): mov [ebp-4] , var1

Comment: Also arguments for called functions are pushed onto the stack.